# How does Delphi's try...except work for sub-procedures? Does exceptions handling work for sub-procedure?

Tags: delphi, exception, stored-procedures

I do not quite understand and I could not find the answer to the question bothering me. Can the try..except block catch and pass the sub-procedure exception?

Let's say that i have code:

```
  try
    ProcedureA;
  except
    on E : Exception do
      ...
  end;
```

and code for ProcedureA

```
procedure ProcedureA;
begin
  SubProcedureA;
  SubProcedureB;
  SubProcedureC;
  ...
end;
```

If SubProcedureB raises exception, will the exception be handled at the main ProcedureA level? Will SubProcedureC be performed? Will the exception be forwarded to procedure A unchanged? Or maybe there is a restriction on sub-procedures, for example, Sub-sub-sub-procedure will no longer pass an exception to the higher-level procedure?

Thank you for the information and I apologize if this is a beginner question (which I am). :)

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Exceptions_(Delphi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If SubProcedureB raises exception, will the exception be handled at the main ProcedureA level?

Yes.  When an exception is raised, it propagates up the call stack until a matching handler catches it.  If no handler catches it, then the process will usually terminate.

> Will SubProcedureC be performed?

*Usually no*, however on Windows at least, it is *possible* (but not with Delphi's `except` syntax) for an exception handler to instruct the system to return back to the original call site that raised the exception.  This is useful in rare cases where an exception handler can actually fix the condition that caused the exception to be raised in the first place, allowing execution to continue from where it left off.  But again, this is very rare.

> Will the exception be forwarded to procedure A unchanged?

*Usually yes*.  There is only 1 `Exception` object in memory, and it is passed to each exception handler on the call stack until a matching handler is found.  That being said, it is *possible* for an exception handler to catch an exception, modify it (it is just an object in memory, after all), and then re-raise it to continue the search up the call stack for another handler.  That is not the case in your example, but it is allowed.

> Or maybe there is a restriction on sub-procedures, for example, Sub-sub-sub-procedure will no longer pass an exception to the higher-level procedure?

There is no such restriction.

Comment: Thank You for that - best answer ever. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try except block catches the exception at any level. The exception is thrown up until it is processed.

Top level is Application.OnException event.

Comment: "*Top level is Application.OnException event*" - not always. That is true for main UI thread in GUI apps, but not for console apps, or worker threads.